# Count the lengths of the first words in the file in gawk

Tags: bash, awk

I need to count the lengths of the first words in the file via gawk.

Use next code:

```
      BEGIN {
        {print "length sum"}
        {print; sum += length($1)}
      }
      {print "summa=", sum}
```

This returns lines with "summa= 0".

example input: example: gawk -f many? Potholderz

example out:

> length sum
>
> summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa=
>   0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0
>   summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa=
>   0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0
>   summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa=
>   0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0
>   summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa=
>   0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0 summa= 0

How to fix it?

Comment: Please add example input and desired output.

Comment: Does it have to be gawk? ;) Are words separated by spaces?

Comment: example: gawk -f many? Potholderz

Comment: Do you mean first word on each line?

Comment: output: length sum

summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0
summa= 0

Comment: Please add these examples to your question in a form that can be understood.

Comment: @Barmar , yes. Length of first word on each line.

Comment: Sorry but this is really unclear. What do you mean with `example: gawk -f many? Potholderz ` What is `many` and what is `Potholderz`. What we are after is a [mcve]. Please update your question with a sample input, the expected output and a clear statement why your code fails.

Comment: @kvantour, the problem has been solved thanks to Barmar.

Comment: @DumbSimon I'm happy to hear that. Nonetheless, could you please update your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BEGIN` clause runs before processing any lines, so there's no `$1` available there.

You need to get the length while processing each line, not at the beginning.

```
BEGIN { print "length sum" }
{ print "summa = ", length($1) }
```